# Interpretting overlapping histogram

Tags: data-visualization, inference, histogram

I obtained the following histogram when performing data analysis. This histogram refers to the duration of cab trips in the NYC taxi dataset.

The histogram clearly shows two overlapping populations with similar distribution shape, but I'm not able to interpret it beyond that and can't think of the reason behind this peculiar observation.

Any idea as to why we are observing overlapping peaks?

[image]

Comment: Histograms often look silly when the bin widths are too narrow. Try wider bin widths. I would guess that your bin widths are narrow enough to suffer from discontinuities in the data values. (When asking questions here, try to supply a bit more information.)

Comment: This is partly an "aliasing" problem due to the lattice nature of the data and the use of bin widths not well adapted to the lattice spacing.  It is also partly (strong) evidence that many durations were recorded to the nearest minute (multiple of 60 seconds): notice how the spikes occur on average at 60-second intervals.  Both phenomena strongly suggest plotting a histogram with breaks at integral multiples of 60.